# Update array by index and not by value in Meteor (MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor (server side) I need to update document with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
  "foo" : {
    "bar" : [1, 2, 3]
  },
  "owner" : 1
}
```

I need to update array value by its index, not by value. When I try something like

```
{owner: 1}, {$set: {'foo.bar.1': 100}}
```

the document becomes like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
  "foo" : {
    "bar" : {
      "1": 100
    }
  },
  "owner" : 1
}
```

which is not what I need. I can change document structure to

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
  "foo" : {
    "bar" : [ 
      {
        "period" : 1,
        "value" : 4000
      }, 
      {
        "period" : 2,
        "value" : 0
      }
    ]
  },
  "owner" : 1
}
```

and then use

```
{owner: 1, "foo.bar.period": 1}, {$set: {'foo.bar.$.value': 100}}
```

which works as expected, but I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: you can fetch the array, update it using underscore array functions and then push it back. It is a two step process. Or you can perhaps use findAndModify

Comment: I tried it using the native mongo shell and it works. It may be a driver problem/mongo version.

Comment: Yeah, in mongoshell it works, but Meteor seems to have its own ways.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only update an array element by matching it's value[1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)

If you only have the array index, you're out of luck. Best to go with your second example.